# Parenthesis inside chemfig environment

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How to display "(" or ")" inside chemfig environment. For example I what to write following chemical formula:

[image]

My try, I used \text{(} and \text{)} to get "(" and ")" inside the chemfig environment. But I now can't able to get the double bond 'O' properly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times,chemfig,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{3 \text{(} ^{-}OC=OCH_2 \text{)}_2C \text{(} OH \text{)} C=OO^{-}}
\end{document}
```

I get following output:

[image]

When I try to make the double bond vertical by adding "[:90]" in between '=' and 'O':

```
\chemfig{3 \text{(} ^{-}OC=[:90]OCH_2 \text{)}_2C \text{(} OH \text{)} C=[:90]OO^{-}}
```

I get weird output like:

[image]

Any suggestion will be of great help.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way. Basically I first write the horizontal part of the molecule and at the end I add the oxo parts. Usually parentheses denote branches for`chemfig`. In order to print them they must be put in braces.  The real branches at the end can be placed at the right position with `chemfig`'s *departure atom* option (the number at the third position in the option of the bonds).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{{(^{-}O}CC{H_2)}_2C{(OH)}CO^{-}(=[2,,2]O)(=[2,,5]O)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It work well. Thanks.